SQL state: 42P01 Character: 101
SELECT * FROM public.emp


---Exchange the seat of odd student with even student and of last student is odd don`t change his i
with student as
  (select id,name,
     row_number() over (order by id) as row_num
   from public.emp
)
update student
set id=case
         when row_num % 2= 1 then lead(id) over (order by row_num)
         when row_num % 2= 0 then lag(id) over (order by row_num)
      end
where row_num <(select max(row_num)from student) 
    or row_num % 2=0;

Error im getting postgres
ERROR:  relation "student" does not exist
LINE 5: update student
^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 101
What should i try to remove above error?`
